# Bokeh line chart is plotting weird

Tags: python, python-3.x, bokeh

I am trying to plot chart in my data science project. And I want to plot chart in this way
[image]
which is produced by Matplotlib library. And now I want to plot in the same way. But it gives me this way in bokeh.

[image]

My data for this in the form of python list and it is as below:

```
ages = [45.0,50.0,55.0,40.0,60.0,35.0,65.0,30.0,70.0,25.0,75.0,20.0,80.0,85.0,15.0,90.0,10.0,0.0]
ageCounter = [4466,4270,3824,3576,3240,2850,2527,2358,1968,1544,981,655,419,149,132,80,17,2]
```

Is there any thing I am missing.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You need to sort the arrays together by age. Bokeh plots the points in the order you pass them in. The data above is out of order which explains the "zigzag".